# Facebook Android 3.0 get user information from access token

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

In the SessionLoginSample example from the Facebook for Android 3.0 SDK, the LoginActivity returns an access token in the session object.

How do I get user information from this access token?

Do I need to manually write a network call to the `/me` url endpoint, or is there a mechanism within the Facebook Android SDK which will do this for me using the access token

Answer (score 1):

The access token provides you the possibility of making request to the Facebook APIs accordingly to the access type and permissions related to it. With this you can manually do [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/graphapi/) requests, that are low-level HTTP-based API. (See also the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer))

If instead you want to benefit from the SDK I suggest you to set up an Android project following the [Getting Started guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/). In fact the SessionLoginSample already uses more complex objects (like sessions), in order to avoid to using "explicitly" the Graph API.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Request.newMeRequest](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request#newMeRequest%28Session,%20GraphUserCallback%29) method. Pass in the session, and a callback, and it will call you back once it finishes.

```
Request meRequest = Request.newMeRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), new Request.GraphUserCallback() { ... });
meRequest.executeAsync();
```